# getelementsbyname doesn't work with var[x]

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to read some hidden fields like:

```
<input type="hidden" name="check[0]" value="5276de80e3b91e48cc7d3c99db785c40">
<input type="hidden" name="check[1]" value="836251738362638404843399db785c40">
...
```

`getElementByName("check")[0].value` returns only `undefined`.
How can I get the real values?

Comment: Well, there is no element with that name. You have two elements with names `check[0]` and `check[1]`. So I guess you want `getElementsByName('check[0]')[0].value`.

Answer (score 1):

The method is named `getElementsByName`, and it returns a `NodeList` of found items.

The name of the elements are `check[0]` and `check[1]`, HTML names doesn't have a concept of element arrays by naming them with an index.

So, to get the values you need to access the items on at a time. Note that you need to use `[0]` to access the element returned, as it's always a list even if there is only one element:

```
var check0 = document.getElementsByName('check[0]')[0].value;
var check1 = document.getElementsByName('check[1]')[0].value;
```

Answer (score -1):

This is what you would want to use:

```
document.getElementsByName("check[0]");
```

i.e

```
getElementByName("check[0]").value
```